# NginX reverse proxy without pass path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I want to use "proxy_pass" of reverse proxy in Nginx with this behaviour:

- when someone try to go to "https://myweb.com", proxypass redirects to "https://myproxyweb.com"
- when someone try to go to "https://myweb.com/foo", proxypass redirects to "https://myproxyweb.com"

In summary, I want to proxypass all paths to the root of my proxy web.

I have this, but doesnt work:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://myproxyweb.com/;
    }
```

It doesnt work because when I try to go to "https://myweb.com/foo", Nginx try to show "https://myproxyweb.com/foo"

Comment: Use `location / { rewrite ^ / break; proxy_pass https://myproxyweb.com; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
server
{
  listen 443 ssl http2:
  server_name myweb.com;

  # TO DO: Configure SSL certificate

  location /
  {
    return 301 https://myproxyweb.com$is_args$args;
  }

  location /foo
  {
    return 301 https://myproxyweb.com;
  }
}

server
{
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name myproxyweb.com;

  # TO DO: Configure SSL certificate

  ...

}
```